# How to disable the app close confirmation dialog in Google AppSheet App?

Tags: google-appsheet

I created my first my Google AppSheet App in Google sheets. It is super easy to display my data in app form. Editing and delete a row is also easy, simply selecting required check boxes. Except one thing.

When I close the app, it shows a confirmation dialog. I want to disable that.

I searched. but couldn't find any setting to turn off the app close confirmation dialog popup. Is there any?

This is the confirmation dialog

[image]

Comment: Please give some details: What language/framework/OS are you using?
Without that - it will be hard to give you an accurate answer

Comment: @SShahar Hi, It is Google AppSheet, GUI to create an app from google sheets. No coding at all.